# I don't know how to create this sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables like this:

[image]

And now how to get ID,NAME and TEXT from tab1(blue) depending on what is assigned in tab3(red) - but only (as in this example) when to tab1.ID = 1 i have assigned 2222 and 1111 in tab3. Something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.ID, e.NAME, e.TEXT 
FROM 
    tab1 AS e 
JOIN 
    tab3 AS c 
WHERE 
    e.ID = c.tab1ID 
    AND (c.tab2name = 1111 AND c.tab2name = 2222)
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT e.ID, e.NAME, e.TEXT 
FROM tab1S e 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab3 c WHERE e.ID = c.tab1ID AND c.tab2name = 1111) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab3 c WHERE e.ID = c.tab1ID AND c.tab2name = 2222);
```

You are only selecting columns from `e`, so you don't need to join `c` in.  I am guessing the `select distinct` is superfluous because the `join` introduces the duplicates.

Comment: But if I would like only those which have exactly these 2 numbers? Not those that contain. How to do it then?

Comment: @PapaSmerf . . . If I understand correctly, you would add another `NOT EXISTS` condition.

Answer (score 0):

This clause is impossible to satisfy: `(c.tab2name = 1111 AND c.tab2name = 2222)`. You're basically looking for a single record with two values. What you need to look for is the existence of two separate records. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.ID, e.NAME, e.TEXT 
FROM 
    tab1 AS e 
WHERE e.ID IN (
    SELECT tab1ID
    FROM tab3
    WHERE tab2name = 1111)
AND e.ID IN (
    SELECT tab1ID
    FROM tab3
    WHERE tab2name = 2222)
```